# Dynamically add JavaScript resources in Thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have timeago.js plugin which need some file for locale. But you can't add all at once. It should be relative current locale. So I need something like switch or if condition to add resources. I've tried this, but it's not working.

```html
<script th:if="${#locale == 'az_AZ'}" th:src="@{/resources/jquery/js/jquery.timeago.az.js}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script th:if="${#locale == 'ru_RU'}" th:src="@{/resources/jquery/js/jquery.timeago.ru.js}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using `#locale.language` to get only the language portion of the context's locale - especially since that is what you need to match for the JS file name.

So, something like this:

```
<script th:inline="javascript" 
        th:if="${#locale.language == 'en'}"  
        th:src="@{/resources/jquery/js/jquery.timeago.en.js}" 
        type="text/javascript"></script>
<script th:inline="javascript" 
        th:if="${#locale.language == 'ru'}"  
        th:src="@{/resources/jquery/js/jquery.timeago.ru.js}" 
        type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But you can go further and simplify this by using that `#locale.language` value directly in your `src` URL:

```
<script th:inline="javascript" 
        th:src="@{/resources/jquery/js/jquery.timeago.{lang}.js(lang=${#locale.language})}" 
        type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Now, there is no need to use any `th:if` statements, and you only need one `<script>` tag, instead of a potentially long list of them.

Comment: Thank you. Side note, in case you need to consider this... Neither approach will provide a "default" or "fallback" language code, if the locale does not have a related JS script. A different approach may be needed for that. Two possibilities: evaluate the locale on the server; use a Thymeleaf `switch` statement.

Comment: I forgot to mention what is probably the best way of all: Use Thymeleaf [properties files](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#using-thtext-and-externalizing-text) to handle localization. This also lets you define a default/fallback file.